# Checking if value is present in df1 from df 2 if not delete row in r

Tags: r, dataframe

Currently, I have two data frames. The first df1 contains two columns which represent network ties. The other df2 contains a single column with the list of all cases for which I have attribute data.

I want to search for those cases from df2 in df1, if they are not present in one or both columns from df1, I want to delete that row. Thus, I will end up with a df1 that contains network ties between cases I have attribute data on.

df1 has about 2.4 million ties (edgelist), and df2 has 34k individual cases.

This is what I have attempted after googling for a while:

First I duplicate the two columns on df1 to have a backup.

```
library*dlypr)
df3<- df1%>%
     mutate(friendid = friendid %in% df2$V1,
            friendid = friendid*1.0) #converts boolean to numeric
df3<- df3%>%
     mutate(tieid= tieid%in% df2$V1,
            tieid= tieid*1.0)
#So what I think is going on here is that if the number is not found it turn the value into 0 and 1 if present. I do this for the two original columns from df1.

#Then I attempt to delete the rows by searching for 0 values on each column (2 and 3, which contain the edgelist).

df3<-df3[apply(df3[2],1,function(z) !any(z==0)),] 

df3<-df3[apply(df3[3],1,function(z) !any(z==0)),]
```

The process does delete a bunch of rows, but I end up with about 2k cases. That does not seem right. I attempted a similar approach doing Excel, but it has a limit on the number of rows you can load at once. After dividing the dataset into three different files and using Kutools, I ended up with about 74k cases. But since I was doing a lot of manual work, I am pretty sure there are errors in the excel work. R allows me to load up all the data at once, which would help in getting a more concrete result.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

EDITED to provide more info:

```
> head(df1)
    ID     steamid    friendid daysknown    years         el1         el2
1    NA 7.65612e+16 7.65612e+16      2156 5.902806 7.65612e+16 7.65612e+16
2    NA 7.65612e+16 7.65612e+16      3480 9.527721 7.65612e+16 7.65612e+16
3    NA 7.65612e+16 7.65612e+16      1588 4.347707 7.65612e+16 7.65612e+16
4    NA 7.65612e+16 7.65612e+16       501 1.371663 7.65612e+16 7.65612e+16
5    NA 7.65612e+16 7.65612e+16       858 2.349076 7.65612e+16 7.65612e+16
6    NA 7.65612e+16 7.65612e+16       686 1.878166 7.65612e+16 7.65612e+16
> head(df2)
                 V1
1 76561197960265800
2 76561197960266000
3 76561197960266100
4 76561197960267800
5 76561197960268100
6 76561197960268400
```

Both columns steamid and friendid in df1 need to be ids available in df2$V1. If only one of the ids is present in the pair that row has to be removed, also if none are present too. The end df will have pairs of ids that can only be found in df2.

Comment: Please provide a minimum reproducible example

Comment: Edited to include more info

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
df2$flag <- 1 #create a lookup column

df_temp <- merge(df1, df2, by.x = "friendid", by.y = "V1", all.x = TRUE)
names(df_temp) <- c("friendid", "tieid", "flag_1")
df_new <- merge(df_temp, df2, by.x = "tieid", by.y = "V1", all.x = TRUE)
names(df_temp) <- c("friendid", "tieid", "flag_1", "flag_2")

df_final <- subset(df_new, df_new$flag_1 == 1 | df_new$flag_2 == 1)
```

First, you are trying to check which friendids match from df1 and df2. Then you are checking which tieids match between the new dataframe and df2. Then you will subset the newly created dataframe to only retain the rows where either one is 1

Comment: Attempted this, but it returned a df with 0 observations. Had this warning message:
Warning message:
In merge.data.frame(df_temp, ids, by.x = "steamid", by.y = "V1",  :
  column names ‘NA’, ‘NA’, ‘NA’ are duplicated in the result

Comment: Did you replace "tieid" with "steamid"?

Comment: Also you will have to include all the columns names in the `names(df_temp) <- c("friendid", "tieid", "flag_1")` statement to include all the columns in df1. This statement basically renames the column names

Answer (score 0):

Hello Juan Arroyo Flores, welcome to stackoverflow.

Im not sure if i got you right, but i think you can use the %in% operator to solve this.

df$variable1 %in% df2$variable will check for every element of df$variable1 if it is present in df2$variable.

```
    df1 = data.frame("name1" = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), "name2" = c("f", "g", "h", "i"), stringsAsFactors = F)
    df2 = data.frame("names" = c("a", "g", "i"), stringsAsFactors = F)

    df1
    df2


    # name1 name2
    # 1     a     f
    # 2     b     g
    # 3     c     h
    # 4     d     i
    # > df2
    # names
    # 1     a
    # 2     g
    # 3     i

    # so we want to have row 1 selecet (cause of a), row 2 (caus of g) and row 4 (caus of i)
    # row 3 gets deleated

    # lets use %in% 

    df1$name1 %in% df2$names

    # > df1$name1 %in% df2$names
    # [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE

    df1$name2 %in% df2$names

    # > df1$name2 %in% df2$names
    # [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE

    # to combine both a or is needed

    df1$name1 %in% df2$names | df1$name2 %in% df2$names

    # > df1$name1 %in% df2$names | df1$name2 %in% df2$names
    # [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE

    # with which you can select the index 
    select_index = which(df1$name1 %in% df2$names | df1$name2 %in% df2$names)
    select_index

    # > select_index
    # [1] 1 2 4

    # now this can be used to select the desired rows
    df1[select_index,]

    # > df1[select_index,]
    # name1 name2
    # 1     a     f
    # 2     b     g
    # 4     d     i

    # you could as well just use 
    df1[df1$name1 %in% df2$names | df1$name2 %in% df2$names,]

    # > df1[df1$name1 %in% df2$names | df1$name2 %in% df2$names,]
    # name1 name2
    # 1     a     f
    # 2     b     g
    # 4     d     i

or with dplyr

filter(df1, name1 %in% df2$names | name2 %in% df2$names)

# > filter(df1, name1 %in% df2$names | name2 %in% df2$names)
# name1 name2
# 1     a     f
# 2     b     g
# 3     d     i
```

not sure if this is what you're looking for?

Comment: I think this gets close to what I want. It definitely removed some rows. But I went back to excel with the resulting data frame and it still contained ids that are not present in df2. I have added some more info to the original post. Thanks

Comment: I've read your updates. If both steamid and friendid have to be present in df2 it should be enought to change the | to &. 
filter(df1, steamid  %in% df2$V1 & friendid %in% df2$V1) hopefully gives what you need.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing not sure if it correct. But with help from SmitM and TinglTanglBob's code I came up with this:

```
#This looks for the id number on the steamid column and returns a new variable tf1 with a logical value of T or F. The same goes for the friendid column returning results to tf2
df1$tf1<-df1$steamid %in% df2$V1
df1$tf2<-df1$friendid %in% df2$V1

#The I do two subsets, first a subset of df1 where tf1= TRUE and then a second subest out of that one where tf2= TRUE
df3<-subset(df1,subset = tf1 %in% 'TRUE' & tf2 %in% 'TRUE')
df4<-subset(df3,subset=tf2 %in% 'TRUE')
```

The sad part is I ended with a lot less data than I thought I had. At least if I am doing it right.